# How to use JSON with difficult objects

Tags: java, json, api

I have problem with dynamic JSON data. I don't know how to put it into my JAVA class. I need "routes" data. But i don't know what i should do with this ""2019-05-27": {...".

It is part of JSON file...

```
{
  "2019-05-26": {
    "lastUpdate": "2019-05-26 06:05:02",
    "routes": [
      {
        "routeId": 107,
        "agencyId": 18
      },
      {
        "routeId": 222,
        "agencyId": 22
      }
    ]
  },
  "2019-05-27": {
    "lastUpdate": "2019-05-27 06:05:02",
    "routes": [
      {
        "routeId": 33,
        "agencyId": 14
      },
      {
        "routeId": 345,
        "agencyId": 2232
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The code below doesn't work. It is not `Map<String,Map<String, String>>`. I think it is -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
    Map<String,Map<String, String>> map = null;
    try {
        map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("routes.json"), mapType);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What should I do to take this data ?

Comment: Use a `Map<String, SomeClassWhichMapsToTheStructureOfTheObjectContainingLastUpdateAndRoutes>`

Answer (score 2):

Create POJO classes like that :

```
public class MyObject {
    private List<Route> routes;
    private String lastUpdate;

    public MyObject(List<Route> routes, String lastUpdate) {
        this.routes = routes;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    // assume getters and setters
}

public class Route {
    private String routeId;
    private String agencyId;

    public Route(String routeId, String agencyId) {
        this.routeId = routeId;
        this.agencyId = agencyId;
    }
    // assume getters and setters
}
```

To test it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/resources/data.json")).collect(Collectors.joining());

        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, MyObject>>() {}.getType();
        Map<String, MyObject> map = gson.fromJson(json, mapType);

        map.forEach((s, myObject) -> System.out.println(s + " " + myObject.getLastUpdate()));

}
```

The output is :

```
2019-05-26 2019-05-26 06:05:02
2019-05-27 2019-05-27 06:05:02
```

You just need to create a map which has date as a key and custom object as value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line :

```
json = Files.lines(Paths.get("routes.json")).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

this line may store null value and that's why you are getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Please check this by debugging. I think you will get the solution.